# GraphQL to JSON parsing?

Tags: json, parsing, graphql, formatting, backend

Hi I am trying to format my graphql query to json request like this. I want to pass id as string with value "3", RN when I am sending this as a json request , graphql denies with error. How do I resolve this ?

```js
{"query":"{user(id:3){id,firstName,age}}"}  {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "String cannot represent a non string value: 3",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Added schema in edit1:
`# Exposes a URL that specifies the behavior of this scalar.
directive @specifiedBy(

## The URL that specifies the behavior of this scalar.

url: String!
) on
| SCALAR

schema {
query: RootQueryType
mutation: Mutation
}

type Company {
id: String
name: String
description: String
users: [User]
}

type Mutation {
addUser(firstName: String!, lastName: String, age: Int!, socialSecurity: String, companyId: String): User
deleteUser(id: String!, companyId: String): User
editUser(id: String!, firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int, socialSecurity: String, companyId: String): User
addCompanies(name: String!, description: String): Company
editCompanies(id: String!, name: String, description: String): Company
}

type RootQueryType {
user(id: String): User
company(id: String): Company
}

type User {
id: String
firstName: String
lastName: String
age: Int
socialSecurity: String
company: Company
}
`

Comment: Here is the graphql query: query{
  user(id: "3"){
    firstName
    age
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Without having the schema it is a bit hard to be sure, but it seems like you need to change the type of the input `id` of the `user` field from `String` to `ID`. The scalar `ID` type does accept strings and numbers as input.